# Recursively matching against a list of words in R

Tags: r, string, list, recursion, match

I am using the following function to create a new column in a dataframe based on partial string matching other column:

```
ff = function(x, patterns, replacements = patterns, fill = NA, ...)
{
stopifnot(length(patterns) == length(replacements))
ans = rep_len(as.character(fill), length(x))    
empty = seq_along(x)
for(i in seq_along(patterns)) {
    greps = grepl(patterns[[i]], x[empty], ...)
    ans[empty[greps]] = replacements[[i]]  
    empty = empty[!greps]
}
```

I am doing this recursively for a list of files. For each file I need to match its name within the 'sName' column. If the file name is present, the new 'match' column reads 1 (and zero otherwise).

```
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".csv")
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
    foo<-read.csv(file.names[i], header = T, sep = ",")
    foo<-data.frame(foo)    
    fname<-gsub(".csv", "",file.names)      
    foo$match<-ff(foo$sName, c("fname[j]"),
    c("1"), "0", ignore.case = TRUE)        
 }
```

The matching is not done, could you please help me?

Comment: What is your actual error? Example of bad output? Example of input data structure?

Comment: No error. I have just a bad output (i.e. no matching is done).

Comment: Can you publish example of bad output? What is the input data structure? What do you expect to happen? What do you actually obtain?

Comment: I think the problem is trying to match 'fname[j]'. For instance, if I search the 'file name', it works. The input data are csv.files which contain several columns. It seems that the function ff expects strings and I am not getting them from my list of files.

Comment: You're trying to find the literal string `"fname[j]"` in the file name, instead of the value of `fname[j]`.  Also, `file.names[I]` will always be of length 1, so there's no reason to loop over `fname`.

Comment: An example would be, reading the file 'abc' I'm trying to match 'abc' in the sName column. I can see the word 'abc' is present in the sName column but the match is zero.

Comment: Thanks @NathanWerth. You are right, I'm looking for the literal string "fname[j]" and no need to loop over file.names[i] (I edited my question). However, if the word doesn't match exactly "fname[j]" (e.g. I find 'abc1' or 'abc_x') my code doesn't pick it.